# All elements change size and position when i resize the window

Tags: html, css, position, size

I'm new to `CSS` and `HTML`, now I got this school project where I've made an imaginary business site. Problem started already on the front page, when I resize my window, all my elements change position and size. What do I do?

I've asked chat GPT and tried to browse for answers online. Chat GPT telling me to use one unit for example % or px, but I dont think that is the problem (?)

This is first time posting a question, hopefully someone can help me out.
Here is my CSS:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }


.navigationBar{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

nav{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navBox {
  position: fixed;
  left: 17%;
  top: 1%;
  border: 10px;
  border-style: double;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-color: #edc967;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #edc967, inset 0 0 20px #edc967, 0 0 20px #ef1c1c, inset 0 0 10px #ef1c1c, 0 0 5px black, inset 0 0 20px white;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 19px;
  cursor: default;
}

h2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1%;
  left: 1%;
  border: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-style: double;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.433);
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 1;
  color: rgba(255, 34, 0, 0.885);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #b84444, 0 0 20px rgba(255, 34, 0, 0.885), inset 0 0 10px rgba(255, 34, 0, 0.885), 0 0 10px #edc967, inset 0 0 6px #edc967;
}

.elope {
  color: #212121;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
  font-family: "brush script MT", cursive;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-shadow: 2px 1px 5px white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition: 1s;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 252, 252);
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px red, 1px 1px 5px #edc967;
}

\#pictureHomePage {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 10px ridge #f9f295;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 79vh;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

\#frontpageBox {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 33%;
  width: 26%;
  background-color: #ff89bab5;
  border: outset;
  border-color: #d0176177;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-radius: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 5%;
}

h4 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: inherit;
  font-size: 4vw;
  letter-spacing: 1vw;
  line-height: 1.3;
  padding-left: 1vw;
  text-shadow: 0 0 7px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 21px #dfbd69, 0 0 42px #dfbd69, 0 0 102px #926f34, 10px 10px 160px #926f34, 1px 1px 10px rgb(224, 7, 7), 2px 2px 5px black, -5px -5px 10px red;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  cursor: default;
}

/\* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- \*/

#bottomPage {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  position: relative;
  top: 605px;
}

.bottomText {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(253, 204, 161);
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  border: 10px double;
  border-color: #ff559d;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 5px 20px crimson, inset 5px 1px 50px #926f34, inset 5px 5px 70px white, 0 0 10px white, 0 0 20px skyblue, 0 0 20px yellow;
  height: 250px;
  width: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13%;
  left: 10%;
  cursor: default;
}

.homepageText {
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.3;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #a67d01, 1px 1px 2px #a9aaae, 1px 1px 5px white, 1px 1px 2px red;
}

\#imageBox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  position: relative;
  top: 62%;
}

.linkImage {
  position: relative;
  width: 15%;
  border: 4px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 7px;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  opacity: .7;
}

.linkImage:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px red, 0 0 20px #faf398, 0 0 40px #926f34, 0 0 30px white, 0 0 70px pink;
  width: 16vw;
  opacity: .9;
}

.clickableText {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #926f34, 0 0 3px white, 0 0 9px #ef1c1c;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.clickableText:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    
    <div id="pictureHomePage">
        <img src="/homepages_background.jpeg" alt="background">
    </div>

    
    
    <div id="bottomPage">
        
        
        <div id="imageBox">
            
            <div class="linkImage" id="weddingPic">
                <a href="wedding.html" class="clickableText" id="marriageText">WEDDING</a>
                <a href="wedding.html"><img src="/wedding.png" alt="marriage"></a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="linkImage" id="divorcePic">
                <a href="divorce.html" class="clickableText" id="divorceText">DIVORCE</a>
                <a href="divorce.html"><img src="/divorce.png" alt="divorce"></a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="linkImage" id="singlePic">
                <a href="single.html" class="clickableText">BLIND WEDDING</a> </a>
                <a href="single.html"><img src="/single.png" alt="single"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- teksten nederst -->
        <div class="bottomText">
            <h3 class="homepageText" id="headLineBottom">GET MARRIED TODAY!!</h3>
            <p class="homepageText" id="introText">Do you dream of getting married but its too long of a process? <br> Are you tired of waiting for the finalization of the divorce papers? <br>
                Fear not! at Vegas Elope we will help you to elope or envelope it (forever..) in a day!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    
        <div id="frontpageBox">
            <h4>ELOPE <br>WITH US <br> TODAY</h4>
        </div>
        
       
        <div class="naviagtionBar">
            <nav>
                <h2> <span class ="vegas"> <strong>
                  VEGAS </span>
                  <span class="elope">ELOPE</span>
                </h2> </strong>
          
                <div class="navBox">
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="home.html">HOME</a></li>
                      <li><a href="wedding.html">WEDDING</a></li>
                      <li><a href="divorce.html">DIVORCE</a></li>
                      <li><a href="blindWedding.html">BLIND WEDDING</a></li>
                      <li><a href="honeymoon.html">HONEYMOON</a></li>
                      <li><a href="aboutus.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        
    </body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: @Paulie_D: is that going to fix my problem. Im gonna check out that site